# Writing tests for a single interface and running them for multiple implementations

Tags: unit-testing, go, interface

Suppose I have the following interface:

```
type UserRepository interface {
   StoreUser(user User) (User, error)
}
```

And the following implementations of that interface:

```
type InMemoryRepository struct {
...
}

func (repo InMemoryRepository) StoreUser(user User) (User, error) {
   ...
}

type PostgresqlRepository struct {
...
}

func (repo PostgresqlRepository) StoreUser(user User) (User, error) {
   ...
}
```

I want to write a unit test for the StoreUser method. But I only need to write it once since the requirements are the same for all the implementation of that interface.

What's the best design to write the test for the interface and then run it with whatever implementation I have?

So far I came up with either:

a) Wrap the test in a test-case loop with all the implementations

```
 testCases := []struct {
    name string
    repo UserRepository
 }{
    { name: "Memory", repo: NewInMemoryRepository()},
    { name: "Postgresql", repo: NewPosrgresqlRepository()},
 }


 for _, tc := range testCases {
     t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing) {
      ...
     }
 }
```

b) Create a test class

```
 type UserRepositoryTests struct {
     UserRepository
 }

 func NewUserRepositoryTests(userRepository UserRepository) UserRepositoryTests {
     return UserRepositoryTests{
         UserRepository: userRepository,
     }
 }

 func (userRepository UserRepositoryTests) TestStoreUser(t *testing.T) {
     ...
 }
```

and call it from the implementation package

```
 type InMemoryUserRepository struct{}

 func (ss InMemoryUserRepository) StoreUser(user users.User) (users.User, error)

 func TestRunInterfaceTests(t *testing.T) {

     dsfnjkf := InMemoryUserRepository{}

     testing := users.NewUserRepositoryTests(dsfnjkf)

     testing.TestStoreUser(t)

 }
```

Although both ways don't sound right to me.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: option `a` seems just fine to me

Comment: @blackgreen what I don't like about that approach is that I would like to keep things separated. How I envisioned it is that someone can develop the core domain logic (and writes the tests for the interface) and then someone else can write a custom implementation without changing the core domain tests

Answer (score 2):

The first approach, where you create a table and iterate over it running each item with `t.Run` is idiomatic in Go. It's what I'd use in this scenario, and in fact I've used this approach many times for exactly the same purpose (multiple implementations of the same interface).

The second approach you describe is rare in Go; it's typically not idiomatic to wrap testing in many layers - tests should be simple and explicit.

---

Regarding your comment; what I think you may be describing is a situation where the writer of the interface wants to provide a test suite that others can invoke on their implementations of the interface. That sounds OK, but why do you need all those levels of abstraction? A function like `RunUserRepositoryTests` should be sufficient - it will take your implementation and a `*testing.T`.

Comment: You are totally right, I was overdoing with the class.
I ended up creating a function to collect all the tests and I call that from my implementation package.
I still wonder though, would the first approach still be the preferred one?